# Best way for passing parameter from top function to bottom across entire service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, parameters, parameter-passing

I was looking for a long time for the best way of passing a parameter from top function to bottom.

Let me explain my situation. I have a Java web-service, I get a parameter from the user, as header in the request and I will need this parameter in the 5th function call.

Controller -> Api -> Adaptor -> local function in the Adaptor -> Exchange.

So, I end up adding parameter to each function call along the way passing this parameter.

The problem is that I will need to do this for ALL the API calls in my service. and it should be unique per request. (can't have it massing around with another request).

I hope my question was clear, i would love to sharpen it if needed.
Thank you.

EDIT1:

Explained example:

Controller(String data) calls to ->

Api(String data) calls to ->

Adaptor(String data) calls to ->

local private function(String data) actually using this data in Exchange(String data) call.

Is there a way to get the data from the Controller to the local private function in the Adaptor without passing this parameter on each function in the way? like context for example, but must be unique per REST request and not session.

I was suggested to create a Properties class which will hold the data and pass it to all the functions. if i will need another field (like I need data now) all i will have to do is add it to the properties class and use getter/setter. for example:

in the controller properties.setData(data) and then:
Controller(Properties prop) -> Api(Properties prop) -> ... -> local private function(Properties prop) and then do prop.getData();

This is a good solution but at this point, will put me under a big refactoring.

Comment: Please provide an example just so that we can improve ur example and answer your question along the way

Comment: Depending on the data, why can't you store the parameter in some other datastructure, then access that later? Show some code why you think you need to pass along one parameter to all the methods.

Comment: @yamenK thank you for your comments, Please see my EDIT 1 on the question. I can not pass code example, but I have no local data structure that i can use, unless it is part of Java, Spring or other beans that might help me achieve my goal.

Comment: @cricket_007 please see upper comment.